# What is the default channel for Android Hotspots?

Tags: wifi-hotspot

I have seen the other threads talking about you not being able to change the default channel, and that is fine as I can configure my router. Can anyone just confirm which one it uses though, or does it vary by manufacturer? If so would you know for Xiaomi and Samsung? Thanks =]

Comment: Not sure there is a default. My Xiaomi  picks channel 149 which is problematic for some Wi-Fi chipsets such as the Realtek 8822CE. Chromecasts struggle with this channel as well, I assume for the same reason. On Windows you can disable 802.11d in device manager but lucked out on my Teclast Android tablet. So I have to stick to 2.4GHz Wi-Fi 4 speeds.

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that on OnePlus you can not choose the channel that is used. You can although choose if you wish to tether via 2.4 Ghz, or via 5 Ghz band.

On the 2.4 Ghz band it picked channel 8, so I doubt there is default to which channel uses, at least not here. It might either pick at random, or do a short channel scan itself and pick an optimal channel.

If you have a second android device, you may use something like [Wifi Analyzer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vrem.wifianalyzer&hl=en&gl=US) to find out which channel your device ended up on.